# Apply clip path to bottom bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I apply a `ClipPath` to a `BottomBar` or a `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter? I am trying to clip around the fourth tab in `BottomBar`(The clipped path should always be around fourth element). This is what I have so far:

```
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.79, 0);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.77, 0, size.width*0.77, size.height*0.2);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.77, size.height*1.2, size.width * 0.61, size.height*1.2,
        size.width * 0.61, size.height*0.2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.61, 0, size.width*0.60,0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.59, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**WHAT I WANT**:

[image]

The fourth element needs to be within the `Center` of the `ClipPath` for all screen sizes within a `Stack`.

Thanks!

Comment: *"How do I apply a ClipPath to a BottomBar in Flutter?"* - so you mean standard `BottomNavigationBar` or any other, custom `BottomBar`?

Comment: @pskink I am using a custom ``Container`` but either works.

Comment: *"[...] but either works."* ??? what you mean by that?

Comment: I want to have the ``ClipPath`` working. I can rewrite the code to use either ``BottomBar ``or ``BottomNavigationBar``. Having a hard time with ``ClipPath`` right now.